# Terraform create multiple VMs using count with different number of vNIcs

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I have a scenario as below:

VM A - Has 1 vNic
VM B - Has 3 vNic

The terraform is generic and has created both VMs - VM A and VM B with count = 2 in the Terraform code. Each VM has just one Nic at the moment. What I need is VM B to have extra 2 vNics. How can this be achieved in Terraform. Im using Terraform 0.13. Any Advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the angle into one VM with multiple NICs and then create the Terraform module for each VM.

A simple example here:

```
variable "vms" {
  default = {
    "VM1" = 1,
    "VM2" = 2
  }
}

module "vm" {
  for_each = var.vms
  source = "modules/vm"
 
  vm_name = each.key
  nic_count = each.value
}
```

On the VM module:

```
variable "vm_name" {}

variable "nic_count" {}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics" {
  count = var.nic_count
  ...
}
...
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  ...
  network_interface_ids = azurerm_network_interface.nics.*.id
  ...
}
```

I only give the key points in the example, you can complete other resources as you need.